# Visual Studio: automatically expand destination of Go To Definition?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, go-to-definition

I'll admit, this is terribly finicky.

When I use Go To Definition on a method, I hate arriving at the destination to find it is collapsed. I then have to locate the method, mouse over to the side, and click the plus sign, or Ctrl+M, Ctrl+M. SECONDS WASTED.

Is there a setting or extension that will automatically expand a collapsed definition in this situation?

Comment: This never bothered me until I just read this post... Damn it, now I must know too...